# SCSS Nesting and extend

Tags: css, sass

When I do a yarn build of the scss below I can only see the .select-list__item:hover in the compiled css, I am not seeing anything else from the class such as .select-list__item--selected I am not sure what the issue here is.

```
%select-list__item {   

&:hover {
    background: red;      
}

&--selected,
&--selected:nth-child(2n),
&--selected:hover {
    background: #00FF00;
 
}}


.select-list__item {
@extend %select-list__item;}
```

Comment: There's a missing `}`

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake when I copied it over

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is to do with how placeholders (ie: `%chosen-name`) are meant to be used.

Although this is not explicitly pointed out in the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors) they are meant to be small bits that are reusable.

At my company, we use one for our generic button styles (margin, padding, font) and we extend that into all of our buttons (primary, secondary, tertiary).

A potential solution for your use case:

```
%select-list__item {   

    &:hover {
        background: red;      
    }
    
    &:focus{
        background: blue;
    }
    
}


.select-list__item {
    @extend %select-list__item;
    
    &--selected,
    &--selected:nth-child(2n),
    &--selected:hover {
        background: #00FF00;
    }
}
```

Or here's another - bit of an OTT solution for the example but you get the idea:

```
%select-list__item {   

    &:hover {
        background: red;      
    }
    
    &:focus{
        background: blue;
    }
    
}

%selected-list__item {
    background: #00FF00;
    &:nth-child(2n),
    &:hover {
        background: #00FF00;
    }
}

.select-list__item {
    @extend %select-list__item;
    
    &--selected {
        @extend %selected-list__item
    }
    
}
```